# Check how many times a string appears in a particular word

Tags: python, debugging

I am practicing my python coding on this [website](http://codingbat.com/prob/p164876). This is the problem

```
Return True if the string "cat" and "dog" appear 
the same number of times in the given string. 

cat_dog('catdog') → True
cat_dog('catcat') → False
cat_dog('1cat1cadodog') → True
```

This is my code , for some unknown reason , i dont pass all the testcases. I have problems debugging it

```
def cat_dog(str):

    length=len(str)-2
    i=0
    catcount=0
    dogcount=0



    for i in range (0,length):
        animal=str[i:i+2]

        if ("cat" in animal):
            catcount=catcount+1

        if ("dog" in animal):
            dogcount=dogcount+1

    if (dogcount==catcount):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Is there a reason for not using the regular expressions?

Comment: `return s.count("cat") == s.count("dog")`

Comment: `animal=str[i:i+2]` gives `animal` a length of `2`, which will always find 0 cats and 0 dogs in each string, making your function always return `True`.

Comment: You should notice that everytime you're outputting `True`

Comment: @cerkiewny I just started on Python hence i still dont know what is regex . Can you point me to a good tutorial to learn thanks

Comment: Sure, [this](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html) is a good place to start, basically this is more general solution to your problem, lets say you are searching not for "dog" but for "dogXXX" where XXX is number of 3 digits, writing every combination would be hard, so you use the regexp that tells computer to search for any digit. And also try reading [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) for the theoretical knowledge what are regexp.

Comment: @cerkiewny: There's a good reason for not using regex here - it's overkill.

Comment: @Tim Yes, that is why it is not an answer but suggestion in comment also OP said he is programming this due to learning reasons and regexp I consider a good thing to learn.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to creat a function,just a line is enough.like:

`return s.count('cat') == s.count('dog')`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative without loop:

```
> def cat_dog(str):
>     total_len = len(str)
>     cat = str.replace("cat", "")
>     dog = str.replace("dog", "")
>     if len(cat) == len(dog):
>       if len(cat) < len(str):
>         if len(dog) < len(str):
>           return True
>     if len(cat) == len(str) and len(dog) == len(str):
>       return True
> 
>     else: return False
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def cat_dog(str):
    count_cat = str.count('cat')
    count_dog = str.count('dog')
      
    if count_cat == count_dog:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.